# Heroku Throwing Error When Running Server

Tags: node.js, heroku, socket.io, permissions, nodemon

I recently made a server that works locally. However, when try to host it on Heroku, I am getting quiet a lot of errors (most of which I have fixed, but one I cannot seem to solve).
One error was that the code I wrote didn't listen on the right port (now changed to `process.env.PORT || 3000`, which works), and another error about nodemon not being present. I fixed it in the dependency part of my `package.json` file by adding `"nodemon": "^2.0.4"`, which clears that up nicely.

However, I may have fixed those, but now when I push my commits and stuff to Heroku and load up my server, the webpage says: `Application error`.

I go to look in the logs (`heroku logs --tail`) and I have a new error.

```
2020-08-14T23:43:55.764028+00:00 app[web.1]: [nodemon] starting `src/app.js`
2020-08-14T23:43:55.783805+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: src/app.js: Permission denied
2020-08-14T23:43:55.799270+00:00 app[web.1]: [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

What is causing the inability to access `src/app.js`? A couple of sites have said to run:

```
npm config set user 0
npm config set unsafe-perm true
```

But I'm unsure how to do this with Heroku. Also, some have said it's unsafe, so not sure if I want to do this.

Is there a very simple way to fix this? Most of my errors aren't that hard, but this one has been an absolute plaque to me.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Rather than using nodemon to execute the `src/app.js` change your package.json start script to `node src/app.js`, not sure if this will fix your issue but it's worth a shot

Comment: @Ameer Im very sorry, I actually fixed it by taking all of the files out of `src`. Not sure why this worked, but it did...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually fixed this issue by taking all of my files out of `src` (and then add `node app.js` as the start command) which seems to clear up the Heroku issue quiet nicely.